# Cannot configure image hosting to aws s3 in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-iam

Recently I have started learning Rails using Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I have completed the tutorial but I have failed to configure image uploading to s3 for user's microposts.

I have already configured the carrier_wave.rb file, I have created an IAM user and an s3 bucket in aws and attached a policy to the IAM user to access my bucket. Nothing seems to work I always get a

```
"Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446436+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response"
```

error when trying to upload images in production

Heroku logs - (I have replaced my heroku app and s3 bucket names in the log by my heroku app, s3 bucket name )

```
[fog][WARNING] fog: followed redirect to <s3 bucker name>.amazonaws.com,         connecting to the matching region will be more performant
2019-04-19T04:52:31.444385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/microposts" host=<my heroku app> request_id=e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a fwd="103.217.242.189" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11246ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2019-04-19T04:52:31.445127+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.445032 #12] DEBUG -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a]    (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-04-19T04:52:31.445581+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.445526 #12]  INFO -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 890ms (ActiveRecord: 37.4ms)
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446356+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.446303 #12] FATAL -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a]
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446434+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.446363 #12] FATAL -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a] Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446436+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446447+00:00 app[web.1]: :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

this is followed by my aws access key and lots of numbers (StringToSignBytes)
then ...

```
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446448+00:00 app[web.1]: :cookies       => [
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446450+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446451+00:00 app[web.1]: :headers       => {
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446453+00:00 app[web.1]: "Connection"       => "close"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446454+00:00 app[web.1]: "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446455+00:00 app[web.1]: "Date"             => "Fri, 19 Apr 2019 04:52:31 GMT"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446456+00:00 app[web.1]: "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446458+00:00 app[web.1]: "x-amz-id-2"       => "G/1U7/WV0h0AAXFPT19ncBYBI7NzwvOKTSMAXyC8DcW7+xTTPfkGALbc+6yRP2MqlUa2x7KMyZc="
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446459+00:00 app[web.1]: "x-amz-request-id" => "B98BDE6CED402707"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446460+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446461+00:00 app[web.1]: :host          => "<s3 bucket name>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446463+00:00 app[web.1]: :local_address => "172.18.241.110"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446464+00:00 app[web.1]: :local_port    => 42310
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446465+00:00 app[web.1]: :path          => "/uploads/micropost/picture/16/IMG_20190307_111228.jpg"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446466+00:00 app[web.1]: :port          => 443
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446467+00:00 app[web.1]: :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446468+00:00 app[web.1]: :remote_ip     => "52.219.104.8"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446469+00:00 app[web.1]: :status        => 403
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446471+00:00 app[web.1]: :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446472+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446475+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.446437 #12] FATAL -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a]
2019-04-19T04:52:31.446512+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-04-19T04:52:31.446476 #12] FATAL -- : [e5749cd5-ba34-40fe-bfc7-86c7ce5e6a6a] app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

s3 IAM user policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my s3 bucket>*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my s3 bucket>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

carrier-wave.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],

    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

I have already set the access key, secret key and bucket using...

```
$ heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY= <access key> 
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY= <secret key> 
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET= <bucket name>
```

My gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'              # Get all ruby gems here

gem 'rails',                   '5.1.6'     
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.12'    
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'    
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.2.2'    
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'    
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'     

gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'    
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'     
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'     
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'    
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'   
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'     
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'    
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.7.0'     
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.7'     

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'                  
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri   
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'     
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'     
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'     
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'     
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'  
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3' 
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14' 
  gem 'guard',                    '2.14.1' 
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'  
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'                     
  gem 'fog', '1.42'                       


end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have already tried changing the s3 bucket region, I have my bucket at the default region and I have verified my Config Vars in heroku, the S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_KEY , S3_BUCKET are correctly set and S3_REGION=us-east-2.

This is my first time working with aws, if someone could help me solve this problem it would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564653/exconerrorsforbidden-expected200-actual403-forbidden)

Comment: I have already went through the above post and I have tried giving all permissions to the IAM user it still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have a clear solution to the problem. There were two problems I had to face...

1. the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'us-east-2', I fixed this error by adding this line

   ```
   :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
   ```

   in my carrier_wave.rb file, then..

   ```
   heroku config:set S3_REGION=<bucket region>
   ```

I also created a new bucket, new IAM user and granted AdministratorAccess to the user

2. Next after resolving this issue I got an error like...

`AccessDenied`

in heroku logs, I have no idea why I am denied access even after setting all the correct policies to the bucket and adding full access right to the IAM user, at last, I was able to get it working by going to my s3 bucket -> Permissions -> public access settings -> edit -> then uncheck the options ...

- Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)
- Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)

I know this gives public access to my bucket, but for now, I only have this option to get it to work, (its a hobby project so public access won't matter to me).

But if anyone comes up with a better solution please tell me...