# Issue in aws s3 bucket with x-amz-server-side-encryption policy not allowing rails5 to upload images but allows in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

We work on rails upgrade from rails 4.1 to 5.2. We face an issue in aws s3 bucket with **x-amz-server-side-encryption policy** not allowing rails5 to upload images but allows in rails4

**s3 bucket has prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3 policy**

**Error:**

> Excon::Error::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
>
> `AccessDenied`

**rails4 gems**

`fog (1.28.0)`

`fog-aws (0.1.1)`

**rails5 gems**

`fog (2.2.0)`

`fog-aws (3.5.2)`

Any suggestion ?? what i'am missing here??

Comment: this error looks more of an error creating a folder in aws rather than a rails issue, are u sure the image folder is getting created on aws ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Thanks for the response. As you said we have both the scenario where will create folder, upload the image and other way without folder. But both are not working.

Comment: What is the permission on the folder ? Also can you add the full logs from when the process starts ....like a full trace log error

Comment: Also did u refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564653/exconerrorsforbidden-expected200-actual403-forbidden

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Yes checked this before. I want to just remind that same s3 bucket works fine in rails4

Comment: This link helped https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/2701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

With gem `carrierwave-2.0.2` 
adding **config.cache_storage = :file** to `config/initializers/s3.rb`

**Solution 2:**

Fixed it by downgrade gem from carrierwave-2.0.2 to carrierwave-1.3.1

**note:**

a. storage with :fog and cache_storage is not configured(but default cache_storage :fog) does not work

b. storage with :fog and cache_storage :file works

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2452